# How does FFmpeg's versioning scheme work?

Tags: ffmpeg, versioning

I paid attention to the FFmpeg version numbers and the only pattern I found is that the 3rd version point (including padding zeros) is the patch number.

Let me show you what I mean by showing you the major releases starting with 5.0:

5.0, 5.1, 6.0

What is the FFmpeg versioning scheme?

Comment: Check out **9 Release process** [[ https://ffmpeg.org/developer.html#toc-Release-process-1 ]] & **9.1 Criteria for Point Releases** [[ https://ffmpeg.org/developer.html#toc-Criteria-for-Point-Releases-1 ]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FFmpeg versioning uses the "major.minor.patch" format. The major number is incremented for major releases with significant changes, the minor number for smaller feature releases, and the patch number for bug fixes and small improvements.